# Magento 2: How to hide quantity box for certain products which has only quantity?

Tags: magento2, cart, catalog, qty-increment

I have certain products, which **customers can buy only one**.

So whether needs to **remove Qty box** for that products only or **can be managed from settings**?

Comment: You can make attribute to add condition for limit in qty box box or hide qty box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a config in Admin: **Log in to Admin > PRODUCTS > Catalog > choose a Product > Advanced Inventory > Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart >** set to 1.

[image]

Overwrite as below

**magento\app\design\frontend\Vendor\YourThemeName\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml**

Replace

```
if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity())
```

With

```
if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity() && ($_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty() != 1)):
```

U need to add

```
$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty()
```

Comment: Not able to get value in `magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml`

Comment: Okay! I will check again.

Comment: Able to get `$_product->getStockItem($_product->getId())` still `max_sale_qty` missing

Comment: Should try: `$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty()`

Answer (score 2):

Create an after plugin for shouldRenderQuantity. In your di.xml, add this.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::configurable-no-render-quantity-field" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Product\View" />
</type>
```

Then in your plugin, do something like this:

```
public function afterShouldRenderQuantity(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $subject, $result)
{
    if ($subject->getProduct()->getTypeId() === \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

Modify the if condition in my sample to achieve what you want.