# magento2 disable user defined quantity on all frontend views for all products

Tags: product, magento-2.1, quantity

I am creating a store for a client by using the porto theme where the quantity box in frontend does not make any sense, so i need to remove it from all frontend view, including in mini cart, cart page, product detail page etc. So is there any setting in admin panel or something where i can easily hide the quantity box from all frontend views ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this just via admin. You can set a max quantity for products to be one however but this does not remove the quantity boxes. This requires a bit of work on the template see here:

[Magento 2: How to hide quantity box for certain products which has only quantity?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155073/magento-2-how-to-hide-quantity-box-for-certain-products-which-has-only-quantity)

The cart may require further work on templates however should only be a matter of copying some template files into your theme and setting a condition like in link above or completely removing the quantity code. This will need to be done for cart and product pages in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Harri, i did this by going through with the templates files one by one, and removed the quantity box from all the places, because i wont be needing this throughout the store.

Answer (score 1):

```
/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

Make a copy of this file into your custom theme so file is overridden e.g.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

You can then make some basic modifications to this file outlined below.

**Disable the Quantity Box**

Add **disabled** attribute to the input box like below:

```
<input data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       'data-item-qty': qty,
                       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                       }, value: qty"
                       type="number"
                       size="4"
                       disabled
                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
```

This was around line 74 for me on version 2.2.1.

**Add logic to enable quantity box**

```
<a data-bind="attr: 
{onclick: 'document.getElementById(\'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty\').disabled = false;'}" class="action edit">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: This looks familiar.