# Hiding the quantity box in the Cart and checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

Is there anyway I can hide the quantity box in the cart from the user? Also in checkout user should not be able to edit cart.

I have upon request from a friendly user posted images of what I would like to get rid of. 2 images, first one is from the dropdown cart and the other one from the checkout/edit cart.

[image: problem 1]

---

[image: problem 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a config in Admin: **Log in to Admin > PRODUCTS > Catalog > choose a Product > Advanced Inventory > Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart > set to 1.**

Comment: 'I have done that but its still there on the checkout page, I cant have it since I use dropdown for quantity. I just need it off the checkout page.

Comment: upload snap ...what you actually want.

Comment: Rohan, I have added the images. Hope they will help you understand what I mean....

Comment: Also by doing what you propose to as https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155073/magento-2-how-to-hide-quantity-box-for-certain-products-which-has-only-quantity the quantity box comes back if the user chooses to edit the product from the minicart.